# How to access to my PHP var

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm lost by retrieving my PHP var. I've tried multiple things without success.

My var is called `$answer` and here is his var_dump :

```
object(stdClass)#3631 (1) { ["token"]=> string(159) "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTQ2MTMyMDQzNCwic3ViIjoiQ2hhdEF1dGhlbnRpZmljYXRpb24ifQ.18jpKLj_6Banyncyq6bz9jIFSB3IRDpBCvSgpIGJPrs" }
```

The most logic is to access by `$answer["token"]` But it's not working.

How can i get my data ?

Comment: It's an object. How did you get it?

Comment: `print $answer->token` ?

Comment: Yes, it's that, it's was stupid i think, sorry for that.
In fact, i got my data with json_decode of the wp_remote_post body response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like an array, but an **object** of `stdClass`. Use the [**Object Operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to access it:

```
$answer->token;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this: `$answer->token`

Comment: First in, plus up from me

Comment: But without an explanation. Writing clear answers with explanation costs time. :(

Comment: Not my question @RohitKhatri but Praveen has a point.. Add an explanation please for OP.

Comment: @RohitKhatri How can someone else mark your answer for their question?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for telling. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access by `$answer->token;` instead of `$answer["token"]`, as it is an object - not an array